# Why does AutoFac's AsImplementedInterfaces break my resolver on another type?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-properties, autofac

In the following code example, the Debug.Assert will fail.

If the AsImplementedInterfaces() extension is removed from the IBreaker registration, foo.Bar will not be null. Why is this the case?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using Autofac;

namespace AutoFacTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IFoo<>).Assembly, thisAssembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IFoo<>))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IBar<>).Assembly, thisAssembly)
               .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IBar<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IBreaker).Assembly, thisAssembly).InstancePerDependency()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces(); //<------ will work if this is removed

        var container = builder.Build();

        var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo<int>>();

        Debug.Assert(foo.Bar!=null);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IBreaker {}

public class BreakerImpl<T> : IBreaker {}

public class BarImpl : IBar<int>{}

public class FooImpl : IFoo<int>
{
    public IBar<int> Bar { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo<T>
{
    IBar<T> Bar { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    public IBar<T> Bar { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar<T>{}

public abstract class Bar<T> : IBar<T> {}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a couple of issues with your registration. First off, understand how `RegisterAssemblyTypes` works: it takes an assembly and discovers all classes in that assembly and registers the types with your builder. You can further augment the call with `AsXYZ` to control how each type is keyed in the final container.

Now, in your sample you are doing this three times, each time with different augmentations, every time you will register *all types*. The first two registrations you are registering all types as closed types of a spesific interface. The third time, you are again registering the same types but now *not* as closed types, effectively breaking the previous registrations.

The solution is to use the `Where` augmentation to limit the scope of which types are registered each time, so that the same types are not registered several times with different augmentations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any filter on your third register call, so it will attempt to reregister all your concrete implementations of IFoo and IBar. When you leave out the AsImplmentedInterfaces(), it will only register the concrete classes as their own type.

Try adding a filter like you did with the other 2 calls.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IBreaker).Assembly, thisAssembly)
            .InstancePerDependency()
            .AsClosedTypesOf<IBreaker>()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

If you were hoping to register all the remaining classes, then try adding Except calls for the classes you already registered.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IBreaker).Assembly, thisAssembly)
            .InstancePerDependency()
            .Except<IFoo>().Except<IBar>() //Not sure if you have to specify the concrete types or if the interfaces are fine
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: You can't use .AsClosedTypesOf<IBreaker>() as IBreaker isn't generic, since AsClosedTypesOf is only for generic registration. Also I'm not following your explanation as to why this is happening. IBreaker and BreakerImpl aren't related to any [I]Foo or [I]Bar interfaces or types, so that registration shouldn't have any effect as far as I can tell.